# PHP variable in HTML table displays well in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, but poorly in IE 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

The table below echos out great in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.  The left part of it displays like this:

[image]

However, in Internet Explorer 8, the left part sometimes displays like this:[image]

In IE8, with short comments, only the top part of the variable `$row["username"]`, which is "admin" in the screenshots, is showing.  How can I make it so IE8 will show the full `$row["username"]` in such a situation?

Thanks in advance,

John

The source code:

```
echo "<table class=\"commentecho\">";
$count = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $dt1 = new DateTime($row["datecommented"], $tzFrom1);  
    $dt1->setTimezone($tzTo1);
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td style="border-left:2px solid #004993; border-bottom:2px solid #004993; border-top:2px solid #004993;" rowspan="3" class="commentnamecount">'.$count++.'</td>';
    echo '<td style="background: #CAE1FF; border-top:2px solid #004993;" class="commentname2user"><a href="http://www...com/.../index.php?profile='.$row["username"].'">'.$row["username"].'</a></td>';
    echo '<td style="border-right:2px solid #004993; border-bottom:2px solid #004993; border-top:2px solid #004993;" rowspan="3" class="commentname1" id="comment-' . $row["commentid"] . '">'.stripslashes($row["comment"]).'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td style="background: #CAE1FF;" class="commentname2">'.$dt1->format('F j, Y').'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td style="background: #CAE1FF; border-bottom:2px solid #004993;" class="commentname2a">'.$dt1->format('g:i a').'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="commentname2a"></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
echo "</table>";
```

The CSS:

```
table.commentecho {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000000;
    width: 450px;
    table-layout:fixed;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px #FFFFFF;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;    

}

table.commentecho td {
   border: 0px solid #fff;  
   text-align: left; 
   height: 20px;


}

table.commentecho td a{
   padding: 2px;
   color: #004284;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-weight:bold;
   height: 20px;
}

table.commentecho td a:hover{
   background-color: #004284;
   padding: 2px;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-weight:bold;
   height: 20px;
}

.commentnamecount { width: 50px;
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 25px;   
            overflow:hidden !important;
            color: #004993;
            font-weight: bold;
            display:table-cell;   
            vertical-align: top;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            padding-left: 5px;
            padding-top: 2px;

}


.commentname2user { width: 120px;
            color: #000000;
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: normal;
            height: 50px;
            padding-top:5px;
            padding-left: 5px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            vertical-align: top;

}

.commentname1 { 
            line-height: 170%;
            width: 410px;
            font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
            overflow:hidden !important;
            color: #000000;
            padding-bottom: 30px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            vertical-align: top;
}


.commentname2 { width: 120px;
            color: #000000;
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 11px;
            font-weight: normal;
            height: 20px;
            padding-top:0px;
            padding-left: 5px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            vertical-align: top;

}

.commentname2 a{ width: 120px;
            color: #004284;
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: bold;
            height: 20px;
            padding-top:0px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            vertical-align: top;

}

.commentname2 a:hover{ width: 120px;
            color: #004284;
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-decoration: underline;
            height: 20px;
            padding-top:0px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            vertical-align: top;

}

.commentname2a { width: 160px;
            overflow:hidden !important;
            color: #000000;
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 11px;
            font-weight: normal;
            height: 40px;
            padding-top:0px;
            padding-left: 5px;
            padding-bottom: 30px;
            vertical-align: top;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you did ask for links to be only that high:

```
table.commentecho td a {
    height: 20px;
}
```

The trick is, this shouldn't work, and doesn't in most browsers: according to the CSS standard, `height` explicitly does not apply to inline elements like `<a>`. However in IE's [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) it does anyway. So:

- remove the ineffective `height:` property
- ensure you serve your page with a Standards Mode DOCTYPE declaration. You don't want Quirks Mode which is full of nasty legacy compatibility bugs like this.

Also remember to use `htmlspecialchars()` when templating data strings into HTML, or you'll have cross-site-scripting vulnerabilities. `stripslashes()` does not do this job and is almost certainly a mistake.

Comment: Ah, okay.  I'll give it a try.  As far as htmlspecialchars() goes, are you saving as a security precaution I should put that on all of the PHP variables?

Comment: Yes. Anywhere you take a string of plain text and drop it into HTML, you need to encode it to fit that context. It's not just security; security is a special case of correctness. An input `<` symbol should usually come out looking like a less-than sign on the page (for which the markup needs to be `&lt;`) and not an accidental HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a line-height issue. try putting an actual pixel/setting a value on the line-height for .commentname2user and .commentname1

Answer (score 0):

I made some arrangements on your php code and your css but this would look pretty much the same in both browsers, hope this helps...

PHP code:

```
echo '<table class="comments" cellspacing="0">';
$count = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $dt1 = new DateTime($row["datecommented"], $tzFrom1);  
    $dt1->setTimezone($tzTo1);
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="comment-count">'.$count++.'</td>';
    echo '<td class="comment-user">';
    echo '<a href="http://www...com/.../index.php?profile='.$row["username"].'">'.$row["username"].'</a>'
    echo '<br/><span class="comment-date">'.$dt1->format('F j, Y').'</span><br/>';
    echo '<span class="comment-hour">'.$dt1->format('F j, Y').'</span>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td class="comment-text" id="comment-' . $row["commentid"] . '">'.stripslashes($row["comment"]).'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
echo "</table>";
```

And your CSS:

```
table.comments{
    margin: 20px 0 30px;
    width: 450px;
}
table.comments td{
    vertical-align:top;
    border: solid #004993;
    border-width:2px 0 2px 0;
}
table.comments td.comment-count{
    border-left: 2px solid #004993;
    width: 50px;
    font:bold 25px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #004993;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding:2px 0 0 5px;
}
table.comments td.comment-user{width:120px;background-color:#CAE1FF;padding: 5px;}
table.comments td.comment-user a{
    font:bold 14px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #004284;
    padding:2px;
}
table.comments td.comment-user a:hover{background-color: #004284; color:#CAE1FF;}
table.comments td.comment-user span.comment-date, span.comment-hour{
    font:11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
table.comments td.comment-text{
    border-right: 2px solid #004993;
    width: 410px;
    font: normal 14px/20px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```